# C# Console.Write using While loop to insert more records?

Tags: c#, loops, console, while-loop, console-application

I want to insert a while loop in the following code in order to insert more than one record.

The code output asks for Name and ID and then print them out in a text file.

Here is my code:

```
Console.Write(" Enter your ID: ");
int ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write(" Enter your Name: ");
string Name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(" Thank you! you are logged in as " + Name + " " + ID);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("fileone.txt", true);
Console.SetOut(sw);
Console.WriteLine("Thank you! you are logged in as " + Name + " " + ID);
Console.Read();

sw.Close();
```

How can I use while loop in order to to let the program ask for another 10 records to enter?

Any answers would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you just need to know how to do a while loop and then you can put it in where ever you need? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: why don't you just put it in a for loop since it is a static number of times it has to run?

Comment: @DROPtableusers: Btw, the reason I downvoted your (now-deleted) answer is that you opened 10 `StreamWriter` objects on one file all the same time and didn't synchronize their write buffers in any way.

Comment: @BenVoigt I was trying to illustrate how you would put a while loop in to loop through their code 10 times, your points are valid admittedly, but not what I was trying to illustrate. I think that your comment would have been more helpful than a down-vote. No big deal.

Comment: @DROPtableusers: I was commenting but you can't leave comments on a deleted answer.

Comment: Sorry @BenVoigt , I made the point I thought would solve the problem as a comment instead of an answer, the downvote made me realize that my answer was not a good way of representing what I was thinking. I didn't want to leave an answer there that would have made no contribution (and most likely get downvoted some more). I am glad the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reformatted your code. You can use Int32.TryParse() while safely convert ID to Integer.

```
                int count = 0;
                while (count < 10)
                {
                    Console.Write(" Enter your ID: ");
                    int ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Write(" Enter your Name: ");
                    string Name = Console.ReadLine();

                    string output = string.Format("Thank you! you are logged in as {0} {1}", Name, ID);
                    Console.WriteLine(output);
                    File.AppendAllText("fileone.txt", output + Environment.NewLine);

                    count++;
                }
```

Comment: It might be desirable to collect all the output in a `StringBuilder` and use just one file I/O call, instead of repeatedly opening and closing the file.

Comment: Does anyone know how to insert update/delete methods in this code in order to delete specific entries/records from the text file? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand.  Wrap your code inside a for loop?

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  ... your code
}
```

Of course you'll have to use the i loop variable to construct a different tile name for each user Id and password pair.